# How to clear part of the buffered image with p5.js

Tags: javascript, rendering, p5.js

I am using javascript with p5.js framework. I created an offscreen graphics buffer. Now I want to clear part of that buffer (so it becomes invisible again). What is the best way to do it?

Right now I can only achieve that by direct changing of the alpha value for every pixel I need.

Here is a MCVE:

```js
// sketch.js, requires p5.js

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
  background(0);
  let mymap = createGraphics(100,100);
  mymap.fill(255);
  mymap.rect(20,20,40,40);
  mymap.loadPixels();
  for (let i = 23; i < 37; i++) {
    for (let j = 23; j < 37; j++) {
      mymap.pixels[400*i+4*j+3] = 0;
    }
  }
  mymap.updatePixels();
  image(mymap,0,0);
}
```

Some side-notes:

1) there is a [tiledmap.js](https://github.com/linux-man/p5.tiledmap) library to p5.js, but I am still reading into it's source code and right now it doesn't look like they got 1 buffer for the entire tilemap.

2) there is a [clear function](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear) to clear the canvas graphics, it does clear things, but it clears everything on the given buffer.

Comment: Try setting the alpha channel of the desired pixels to 0

Comment: @Julian Turns out I can load pixels and set those alpha channel to 0, but I must say this looks a bit like a low-level coding appearing all of a sudden. Gonna rewrite my question anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems I found the answer, but my code is not working anymore for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `set()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/set).

I would expect something like this to work:

```
const transparency = createGraphics(20, 20);
mymap.set(30, 30, transparency);
mymap.updatePixels();
```

Unfortunately, this seems to only set a single pixel. This smells like a bug to me, so I've filed [this bug](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2984) on GitHub.

Like you've discovered, you can also set the pixel values directly. This might be simpler than what you currently have:

```
let mymap;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
  mymap = createGraphics(100,100);
  mymap.fill(255, 0, 0);
  mymap.rect(20,20,40,40);

    for(let y = 30; y < 50; y++){
        for(let x = 30; x < 50; x++){
            mymap.set(x, y, color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    mymap.updatePixels();
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 255, 0);
  image(mymap,0,0);
}
```

Note that there's a tradeoff: this code is simpler, but it's also slower.

Comment: Yeah, I also found out the existence of `set` and came to the conclusion something is not working right there. Saw your bug report, also reported [mine](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2986).
Quite a similar one, but different.